# Installing CentOs 5.5-x86_64 kernel hangs with message NET: Registered Protocol family 2

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I am attempting to install CentOS 5.5 on Oracle VM VirtualBox. I press enter for normal installation, things start to happen and then it hangs with the above message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this [ticket](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5423).

> I must append kernel boot parameter nolapic or enable IO APIC in the settings of the guest

Comment: That was the solution! I enabled IO APIC for the virtual machine and now I am installing.

Comment: nolapic strikes again.

Comment: Alternatively, you can turn on IO APIC in VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Choose Redhat (64 bit) from the Version pulldown of the General Settings->Basic tab screen (it defaults to Redhat) when the initial Setup is being done and the IO APIC will be enabled automatically.